# Update Label text from a top entry box

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('change text')
Label1 = Label(root, text = 'Change me')
Label1.pack()

def presto():
     Label1.configure(text = entry1.get())

def open_sub():
     top1 = Toplevel(root)
     top1.title('Buttons')
     label1 = Label(top1, text = 'Type Something')
     entry1 = Entry(top1, width = 20)
     button1 = Button(top1, text = "execute", command = presto)
     button2 = Button(top1, text = 'close', command = top1.destroy)
     label1.pack()
     entry1.pack()
     button1.pack()
     button2.pack()

 button1 = Button(root, text = 'page 2', command = open_sub)
 button1.pack()

 root.mainloop()
```

The way this program currently works is it creates a root window with a label with the text "Change me". And a button that opens a toplevel window.  In the toplevel window is a label with the text "Type Something". Then an entry box and an execute button and close button. When the execute button is pressed it should change the text in the label on the root window into whatever is typed in the entry widget on the toplevel but I get error code:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/Pydroid3/Character Generator/anothermain.py", line 9, in presto
    Label1.configure(entry1.get())
                            ^^^^^^
NameError: name 'entry1' is not defined
```

Comment: `entry1` is a *local variable* inside `open_sub()` - it's not accessible inside `presto()`, indeed it no longer even exists at the time that function gets called.  You either need to make `entry1` a global variable, or move the definition of `presto()` inside of `open_sub()` so that it can access the variable.

Comment: Making presto an inner function is just as unhelpful as i have already tried that, the way it is written I would like it to be a global variable but I'm not sure how to accomplish this as this program will eventually have multiple top levels changing other labels in the same fashion. To different values. But I'm not even going to try that until I master it the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the input text to `presto()`:

```py
def presto(text):
    Label1.configure(text=text)

def open_sub():
    ...
    button1 = Button(top1, text="execute", command=lambda: presto(entry1.get()))
    ...
```